# Do we have an option to change/override the drupalsettings variable which is defined by some other module through our custom module?

Tags: javascript

What is the best approach to change/override the `drupalsettings` variable which is defined by some other module (basically core) through our custom module ? If I follow the same hooks then how to call it at very last in **Drupal 8**?

Here: by `drupalsettings`, I am asking about the Drupal behaviors variable.

The question is updated as suggested by @leymannx.

Comment: Were does the contrib module attach this variable? Did you try to implement a similar hook and set your own value the same way the contrib module did? What happened? Maybe you then need to ensure to have your implementation run last. Please update your question and provide more details.

Comment: Maybe it works similar to this: https://www.drupal.org/node/2974681. Attach your own JS from where you need it and have it set `Drupal.settings.foobar = 'hello world'` to override the foobar settings declared somewhere else before.

Comment: Thanks for putting your effort @leymannx, your comment is appreciable. I already did the same thing as I was continued debugging. And yes I am on the same page as you have asked, the issue is in the ordering of my module's hook. What will be the best approach to call it last ? some hook like hook_module_implements_alter or using the module modules_weight ?

Comment: Yeah, hook_module_implements_alter. 

Comment: This is usually the last resort and following the same hook is not specific to the topic drupalsettings. These can be defined in different ways. In hook_page_attachments, then there is a hook_page_attachments_alter,  in render arrays, which can be changed like any other rendered content in various hooks of the render pipeline and finally for dynamic overrides there is hook_js_settings_alter.

Comment: Thanks, @4k4, make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the drupalSettings with the hook "hook_js_settings_alter":

```
function hook_js_settings_alter(array &$settings, \Drupal\Core\Asset\AttachedAssetsInterface $assets) {

  // Add settings.
  $settings['user']['uid'] = \Drupal::currentUser();

  // Manipulate settings.
  if (isset($settings['dialog'])) {
    $settings['dialog']['autoResize'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

For more information see: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_js_settings_alter/8.9.x

I checked the code and the theme hook is run after the module hook. So if you really want to be last. Add the hook to your theme.

web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Asset/AssetResolver.php:

```
$this->moduleHandler->alter('js_settings', $settings, $assets);
$this->themeManager->alter('js_settings', $settings, $assets);
```

Comment: You could also use this hook to make sure your module is last: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Extension%21module.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/8.5.x

Comment: Useful findings @andeersg, btw I was looking the way to achieve it through module only. Would you also suggest to replace the existing assets(JS/CSS) with my custom one using the same hook ? or I  should just append my custom js in the $assets->setLibraries()?

Comment: If you want to alter/replace the assets I would recommend this hook: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_library_info_alter/8.2.x, `js_settings_alter` is just for altering the settings.